# Formatting output scala lists

Tags: scala, list

Currently I can search for a value, say `SK5` and it will return all values higher than `SK5`. However the format it is returned in as shown below;

> List((SK6,List(2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2,
>   4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9)), (SK4,List(2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6,
>   6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8)),
>   (SK8,List(2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7,
>   0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6)), (SK9,List(7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7,
>   4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6)),
>   (SK5,List(2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9,
>   3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3)))

What I want is SK6 - 9, SK4 - 8 etc etc

All bundled together, How would I split this up and only show the last number in the list? I thought I had already filtered this out however apparently not. 
Below is my code. `Mapdata` is saved as `Map(String, List[Int])`

```
  //functionality to find the last tail element, the "Current" stock price
  def findLast(list:List[Int]) = list.last


 //8 - Show Stocks Higher Than (W) THIS ONE THIS ONE THIS ONE
  def handleEight(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowPointsForStockHigher(higherThan2)
    true
  }

  //Returns a list value
  def mnuShowPointsForStockHigher(stock: (String) => List[(String, List[Int])]) = {
    print("Enter Stock > ")
    val data = stock(readLine)
    println(s"${data}")
    //println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2.last}")
  }

 def higherThan2(stock: String): List[(String, List[Int])] = {
    mapdata.toList.sortWith(_._2.last > _._2.last).takeWhile(row => row._2.last > mapdata.get(stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to get just a last number/item in the list? then use List.last Use that link for more details: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: I have tried that, It returns the last List only instead of the last value in each list @PavelOliynyk

Comment: you need to use map with last

Comment: Would that not just give me the last list in the lists instead of the last value of each? @PavelOliynyk

Comment: If you are trying to get the last value in each list, Best option will be map + last. Sorry, don't need to use flatten. My bad .. Should be something line: list.map(x => x.last)

Comment: Ive updated my question, in my higherThan2 function, I use "findLast" I've added this to the question. should that not be finding the last value? @PavelOliynyk

Comment: @PavelOliynyk that worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to mark this as an answer:))

Comment: If you format your code to eliminate scrolling, you make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sk4 is interesting. I would have thought you might take the hint and start asking better written questions rather than keep creating new accounts and asking badly worded ones.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul SK(N) does appear to be a [postcode area in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SK_postcode_area) so it is possible that these are questions from different people working with some sort of UK geographic data.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul nevermind, just realized they all have _extremely_ similar format. What is the SO policy on sock-puppeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the last value in each list, Best option will be map + last. Sorry, don't need to use flatten. My bad .. Should be something line: list.map(x => x.last)